# How to pass multiple json object in Ajax posting to get the same in conTroller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have gone through all possible questions here and in google. Didn't find anything useful or maybe I don't know how to change the code accordingly. New in JQuery. Please see my code below.

In a form, master entry and detail entry is there. Here Employee part is the Master and the Member part is the detail and contains multiple rows. I need to pass all recordS on click of a button.

```
var Employee = {
        "Title": "",
        "FirstName": "",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "",
        "Gender": ""
    }
    Employee.Title = $('#ddltitle').val();
    Employee.FirstName = $('#txtfname').val();
    Employee.MiddleName = $('#txtmname').val();
    Employee.LastName = $('#txtlname').val();
    Employee.Gender = $('#ddlgender').val();

    var Member = {  
        "Membername": "",
        "Relation": "",
        "Gender": "",
        "DOB": "",
        "Age": ""
    }

    Member.Membername = $('#txtmem1').val() + "," + $('#txtmem2').val() + "," + $('#txtmem3').val() + "," + $('#txtmem4').val() + "," + $('#txtmem5').val();
    Member.Relation = $('#ddlrel1').val() + "," + $('#ddlrel2').val() + "," + $('#ddlrel3').val() + "," + $('#ddlrel4').val() + "," + $('#ddlrel5').val();
    Member.Gender = $('#ddlgen1').val() + "," + $('#ddlgen2').val() + "," + $('#ddlgen3').val() + "," + $('#ddlgen4').val() + "," + $('#ddlgen5').val();
    Member.DOB = $('#txtdob1').val() + "," + $('#txtdob2').val() + "," + $('#txtdob3').val() + "," + $('#txtdob4').val() + "," + $('#txtdob5').val();

    if ($("#btnSubmit").val() == "Submit") {
        var url = "/Employee/InsertEmployee";
       $.post(url,Employee,Member, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, response) {
                if (response.Result == "Success") {
                    alert("Employee Inserted Successfully");
                    var url = window.location.href;
                    window.location.href = url;
                    ClearFields();
                }
                else {
                    alert(response.Error);
                    var url = window.location.href
                    window.location.href = url;
                    ClearFields();
                }
            });
        });
        return;
    }
```

**My Controller code as below:**

```
public JsonResult InsertEmployee(DMEmployee objEmp,DMMember objMem)
    {
        BLLEmployee obl = new BLLEmployee();
        int i = obl.InsertEmployee(objEmp, objMem);
        int i = 0;
        List<ResultMessage> l = new List<ResultMessage>();
        ResultMessage Rescls;
        if (i > 0)
        {
            Rescls = new ResultMessage();
            Rescls.Result = "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            Rescls = new ResultMessage();
            Rescls.Error = "Enter Valid Credentials";
        }
        l.Add(Rescls);
        return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**DMEmployee and DMMember classes are as below**

```
public class DMEmployee
{
    //Employee Details
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

public class DMMember
{
    //Family Details        
    public string Membername { get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to pass these master and detail values to controller. For detail, I am passing comma separated values to controller. It is not showing any error, break point is also working.

In controller method I am getting objects value as null. Why could that be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way

```
             var Employee = {
            Title: $('#ddltitle').val(),
            FirstName: $('#txtfname').val(),
            MiddleName:$('#txtmname').val(),
            LastName: $('#txtlname').val(),
            Gender: $('#ddlgender').val()
        }

        var Member = {
            Membername: $('#txtmem1').val() + "," + $('#txtmem2').val() + "," + $('#txtmem3').val() + "," + $('#txtmem4').val() + "," + $('#txtmem5').val(),
            Relation: $('#ddlrel1').val() + "," + $('#ddlrel2').val() + "," + $('#ddlrel3').val() + "," + $('#ddlrel4').val() + "," + $('#ddlrel5').val(),
            Gender: $('#ddlgen1').val() + "," + $('#ddlgen2').val() + "," + $('#ddlgen3').val() + "," + $('#ddlgen4').val() + "," + $('#ddlgen5').val(),
            DOB: $('#txtdob1').val() + "," + $('#txtdob2').val() + "," + $('#txtdob3').val() + "," + $('#txtdob4').val() + "," + $('#txtdob5').val(),
            Age: ""
        }

 //creating json multiple object

        var postData = {
            objEmp: Employee,
            objMem: Member
        };
            $.ajax({
                type: "post"
                url: url.
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                success: function (data) {
                    //do you actions
                }
            });
```

Comment: controller will be the same?

Comment: can you please refer some help for Complete WebGrid data posting using Ajax posting

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to pass multiple complex objects (using the above principle) from jquery to a WEB API using JObject, and then cast back to your required specific object type in api controller. This objects provides a concrete type specifically designed for working with JSON.

```
var customer = {
      "Name": "jhon",
      "Id": 1,
};
var product = {
      "Name": "table",
      "CategoryId": 5,
      "Count": 100
};
var employee = {
      "Name": "Doey",
      "Id": 4,
};

var combinedObj = {}; 
combinedObj["obj1"] = customer; 
combinedObj["obj2"] = product; 
combinedObj["obj3"] = employee;

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      async: true, 
      url: 'api/PostGenericObjects/',
      data: JSON.stringify(combinedObj),
      success: function (response) {
            console.log("Response Data ↓");
            console.log(response);
      },
      error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
      }
});
```

and then you can get this object in your ApiController

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public string PostGenericObjects(object obj)
{
      string[] str = GeneralMethods.UnWrapObjects(obj);
      var customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject&lt;Customer&gt;(str[0]);
      var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject&lt;Product&gt;(str[1]); 
      var employee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject&lt;Employee&gt;(str[2]);

      //... other work....

}
```

I have made a generic function to unwrap the complex object, so there is no limitation of number of objects while sending and unwrapping. We can even send more than two objects

```
public class GeneralMethods
{
  public static string[] UnWrapObjects(object obj)
  {
    JObject o = JObject.Parse(obj.ToString());

    string[] str = new string[o.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i &lt; o.Count; i++)
    {
      string var = "obj" + (i + 1).ToString();
      str[i] = o[var].ToString();
    }
    return str;
  }
}
```

I hope it would help someone. [More description of this method can be found on this blog post here](http://tech.sheikharis.com/2017/04/pass-multiple-complex-objects-to-web.html)

Happy Coding!